# Does a closed subspace of the dual of a C*-algebra always have positive elements?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Pardon me if this problem is obvious. I am trying to figure out if given a $C^*$-algebra $A$, whether every closed subspace of $A^*$ has non-trivial positive functionals in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the linear span of a single element of $A^*$ that is neither positive nor negative?

Comment: This was so simple! Thanks very much. I should have put more thought into it.